# WebMatrix Database with Timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, token, webmatrix

I'm having a difficult time attempting to get this thing going, and I don't know why.

I'm attempting to set up a site which is backed by a database.  The company I work for makes this possible through WebMatrix.  I have all my web files uploaded and IIS is running, but when it comes to the database, I can't figure out this one last thing.

How do you set up a column for a timestamp?

Back in phpAdmin, it was simple,  but this is ridiculous.

I add a column with these settings:

```
(Name)            timestamp
Allow Nulls       False
Datatype          datetime
Default Value     ???
Is Primary Key?   False
```

If I leave the Default value line blank I get this error:

> Alter table only allows columns to be added which can contain null
>   values.  The column cannot be added to the table because it does not
>   allow null values.

But if I fill in the value of Default Value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I get this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token
>   line offset = 62, Token in error = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone comes across it (as I did) while looking for a solution, enter `GetDate()` in the Default Value field.